# Google Maps grey dotted lines identified location

Tags: google-maps, privacy, geolocation

I clicked to search for directions on a place on Google and it redirected to Maps.

1. Google was able to precisely identify my location
2. The map displayed several thick grey dotted curves all converging into my location

What are those lines and how was it able to obtain my location (more precisely than the one linked to my IP address and somehow connected with the dotted lines)

No GPS on the laptop and not logged in with a Google account

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Google Maps is able to derive your location from the IP address
2. Grey dotted pathways are alternative routes usually depicting distances needed to overcome by walking

[image: 0]

Comment: It's not the location from my IP, it is more precise, I checked the IP on other sites and it identifies a close place, but not my exact location